# Can two @Path point to the same method in WS(rest)

Tags: web-services, rest

I have two paths @Path("{gpid}") and @Path("{gpid}/vip") I want both to be pointing to the same method but within the method they will be using two different daos, is this possible? Am using web-services using jersey

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can include part of the path as a parameter and then use it inside the method. In Java, this is how you do it:

```
@Path("/{gpid}{isvip : (/vip)?}")
public Response myMethod(@PathParam("gpid") String gpid,
                         @PathParam("isvip") String isvip)
```

Note the use of the regular expression. In the body, check whether the value of `isvip` is null/empty or the string "vip".

Comment: Thanks man for the quick reply, will check it out and get back to u